# Trouble inserting variable in sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite, hashlib

Im having a problem inserting a variable into sqlite3 and the variable is hashed.
Here's my code:

```
if passadefinir == passadefinir2:
    maindb.execute("DELETE FROM Password WHERE ID = 'not'")
    maindb.execute("INSERT INTO Password(ID) VALUES ('set')")
    encriptacao = hashlib.sha1(passadefinir2.encode())
    encriptado = (encriptacao.hexdigest(),)
    maindb.execute("INSERT INTO Password(Password) VALUES (?)" (encriptado,))
    conn.commit()
```

Here's the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "sqlitetesting.py", line 28, in 
>       maindb.execute("INSERT INTO Password(Password) VALUES (?)" (encriptado,))
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Have a nice day :D, 
Luis Duarte.

Comment: Add a `,` before the tuple

Comment: `"string" (stuff, )"` is not valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute using String's `format` method

```
password_var = 'your password'
insert_statement = 'INSERT INTO Password(Password) VALUES ({0})'.format('\'' + password_var + '\'')
```

then run the execute method as:

```
maindb.execute(insert_statement)
```